# How to access kernel parameters in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, procfs

**This is one of my lab assignments:** I have to create an proc entry here: **/proc/sys/kernel/** and *I have to write a system call to manipulate a user space variable for different values of the proc entry I just added.* For eg: say, user space variable is 1 and proc entry is 0 or 1. Now the system call should increment the user space variable by 1(if proc entry is 0/off) or multiply it by two(if proc entry is 1/on)

**I did the following to add the proc entry:** I created an entry xxx by adding a struct under the kernel ctl table section in the file in the kernel/sysctl.c. Compiled the kernel and the system boots well with this kernel. The entry is also added into proc directory as /proc/sys/kernel/xxx.
I am now able to read or write to it from user space. I did both cat and echo to read and write resp.

**I did the following in the system call:** I wrote a system call to read the user space variable. I also completed and tested the access_ok, copy_from user, copy_to_user and all that. I also completed manipulating the user space variable to increment always(for now).

**Problem I am facing:** Now, I have to add an if condition to check the "xxx" value to decide whether I should increment or multiply the user space variable. This is where I am stuck. Not in writing the system call. I don't know how to read this proc entry "xxx".

1. Can I use file handling?
2. If so, should I use open() system call inside my system call? Will it work?

When I checked, there was sysctl system call, but it seems deprecated now. This [IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-proc/index.html) talks about reading the proc entry. But create_proc_entry does not apply to parameters inside /proc/sys/kernel directory right? If so, how can I ever use read proc entry function?

Comment: There was another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400200/how-to-read-write-from-to-a-linux-proc-file-from-kernel-space) similar to this, but they specifically used create_proc_entry for entry under /proc. But, I edited the sysctl.c directly to get an entry under /proc/sys/kernel. So, I am not sure how that answer applies here either.

Comment: You can create a variable which will be exported (visible to other kernel translation units) and will reflect the current value of your parameter. You will have to update it in the new sysctl handler you've implemented, and add the system call to read its value. If your problem is more specific, feel free to update the question.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I am pretty new to this. So can you explain waht do you mean by variable and sysctl handler? I edited the question to better explain what I did and what I am looking for.

Comment: Why is this being voted down? It looks to be a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: @Dipstick Agreed, it's a model question - the OP describes the background to the question, details what they've done so far, and asks specific questions.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I think I understood what you said. I made a global variable in the sysctl.c file and then referenced it with extern keyword in my system call. Hope it works, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

"But, now I have to write a system call to read the value of xxx."

I suspect that the term "system call" is being used in a formal sense and that you are being asked to add a new system call to the kernel (similar to open, read, mmap, signal etc) that returns your value.

See [Adding a new system call in Linux kernel 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977968/adding-a-new-system-call-in-linux-kernel-3-3)

Comment: Yes, formally, I have to write a system call and add it to the kernel. I know how to add it to the kernel. I have edited the question, to be more specific. Please take a look. Thanks